# unable to check if a user is in SharePoint group or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, sharepoint-rest-api

I am checking whether a user is there in a particular SharePoint group or not. i have shared the site with "Everyone" and "NTAUTHORITY\authenticated users". Below is the code i am using to check.

```
function isCurrentUserInGroups(groups) {

    var flag = false;
    var userId = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/GetUserById(" + userId + ")/Groups?$select=title";

    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        type: "GET",
        async: false,
        headers: {
            "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.results.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < groups.length; j++) {
                    if (data.d.results[i].Title == groups[j]) {
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            //alert("Failed to get details");                
        }
    });
    return flag;
}
```

This code works fine if i am directly adding users in group. But not working for users in "Everyone" and "NTAUTHORITY\authenticated users". Please assist.

Comment: *Everyone and NTAUTHORITY\authenticated users" are not SharePoint groups so naturally that won't work.

Comment: @Christoffer any solution? as we want to add all the users in a specific group and validating their presence with the above mentioned code.

Comment: Well, to me it seems that you only need to check if specific users are added to any custom groups? Or else you could just assume that they access the site trough "everyone" permission?

Comment: @Christoffer we have 3 groups, so one group will contain all the users(Everyone) but two other groups will contain different set of users. Now we are hiding some of the tabs from these 3 types of users based on the group in which they exist. This functionality is working when we are adding users directly in groups but not when we are adding "Everyone" in one of the group.

Comment: I understand, but then you should be able to hide everything by default and show the tabs if the user belong to group X or group Y and let "Everyone" see the default/not hidden.